# multiple if statement conditions vba

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm very new to VBA so need a little help. I have a macro (BEM) that is dependent on the value of two cells. I want to be able to run the macro if either of those values is changed. If either of them is blank, I need the code to do nothing until a value is inputted in both cells.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$B$4" And (IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) Or IsEmpty(Range("B4").Value)) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        BEM
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/691852-run-macro-based-text-cell.html

Answer (score 2):

The `and` operator has higher precedence than the `or` operator therefore your `if` condition in its current format is interpreted as if:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Or (Target.Address = "$B$4" And (IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value)) Or IsEmpty(Range("B4").Value)) Then
```

But you want to goup the `or` conditions:

```
If (Target.Address = "$B$3" Or Target.Address = "$B$4") And ((IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) Or IsEmpty(Range("B4").Value))) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing for multiple Ranges, you can use `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B4")) Is Nothing`.

And instead of checking each Cell if `IsEmpty` or `Not`, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.CountA` for an entire range, in your case your range consists of 2 cells, so you want to check that `WorksheetFunction.CountA("YourRange") = 2`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B4")) Is Nothing And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B3:B4")) = 2 Then
    BEM
End If

End Sub
```